# How can I extract these table rows from HTML?

Tags: perl, parsing

I want to find a team score by entering team  after matching then show next number or word after team name to be able to display score.

And I want this to apply on left and right side teams (left side: FT Crystal Palace 1 - right side: 1 Leicester)

The main issue is to find team score from our matching entered team.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;


my $input = $cgi->param("team");
my $response ='';


if ($input) {
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "");
my $res = $ua->request($req);
my $html = $res->decoded_content;

$html =~ s/<span.*?<\/span>//gs;
$html =~ s/<script.*?<\/script>//gs;
$html =~ s/<td(?=[^>]*class="events-button button first-occur")[^>]*>//gs;

my $table = HTML::TableExtract->new();
$table->parse($html);

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

foreach my $row ($table->rows) {
     my $output =  join("", @$row);
     $output =~ s/\R//g;
     print $output;
     
    # Find matching team (Its a must to find team after word FT)
    if ($output =~ m/$input/) {
    
    # After that team the next is score (Gets team scores)
    my $score = $output =~ /$input\s*?(\S+)/;
    
    $response ="Found Team And Score is: $score";
    } else {
    $response ="Can't find team";
  }
}
}


print <<EOF;

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Test</h1>

<form method="post">
  <label for="team">Enter Team:</label>
  <input type="text" name="team"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Find team">
</form>

 <h4>$response</h4>

</body>
</html>
EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using Mojolicious for these things because everything I need is built in. With a little CSS Selector magic, you can easily zero in on the data you want without manual string processing.

Looking at the source, I see that the page has results in a table with class `matches_new` and within that table, the interesting rows have the class `match`. Within those rows, the interesting table cells are in classes `team-a`, `team-b`, and `score-time` (although the "score" may also be a game status).

Note that many of the rows don't load their data until you click on the team name. That's JavaScript at work and a Perl web scraping library isn't going to help you there. I don't know why the English Premier League already has data filled in for me (is it that way for everyone?) or if we can rely on that always being the case.

But let's extract that data.

The basic Mojo HTML-parsing process is to make a request then get the DOM (Document Object Model). In that DOM, `find` and `at` locate particular parts. `find` gets everything that matches its CSS Selector, and `at` gets the next match.

So, I `find` all the right rows, and each row is another (smaller) DOM object that I can explore further to get the teams and score.

The `find` returns a Mojo::Collection (fancy interface to an array) and I call `map` to process each row in turn and extract all the text from each table cell (and `trim` removes the leading and trailing whitespace). The `all_text` gets everything, including text in child nodes.

```perl
#!perl
use v5.10;

use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::Util qw(dumper trim);

my $url = 'https://int.soccerway.com/matches/2020/12/28/';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my @results = $ua
    ->get( $url )
    ->result
    ->dom
    ->find( 'table.matches_new tr.match' )
    ->map( sub {
        my $row = $_;
        my @results =
            map { trim( $row->at( $_ )->all_text ) }
            qw( td.team-a td.team-b td.score-time );
        return \@results;
        } )
    ->to_array;

say dumper( @results );
```

Here is the output, with just the soccer matches :

```
[
  [
    "Everton",
    "Manchester City",
    "PSTP"
  ],
  [
    "Crystal Palace",
    "Leicester City",
    "1 - 1"
  ],
  [
    "Chelsea",
    "Aston Villa",
    "1 - 1"
  ]
]
```

You aren't strictly "wrong" for using LWP or HTTP::Request, but they don't come with powerful tools to handle the data. The HTML::TableExtract is fine, but that table it gets is long and you don't want most of its rows. In my career, I've written many, many programs like the one you presented: grab the source, remove are much irrelevant HTML as you can, and process what's left. Having all the tools in one package where everything is designed to work together in the same milieu is much nicer.

Targeting exactly what you want with selectors is much easier, less fragile, and much less code. You can see this in the [Mojo docs](https://www.mojolicious.org) and I wrote about in it detail with lots of examples in [Mojo Web Clients](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients).

Also, you can just use the Mojo::DOM stuff as long as you have the HTML, no matter the source. I write about this in [Extracting from HTML with Mojo::DOM](https://www.perl.com/article/143/2015/1/8/Extracting-from-HTML-with-Mojo-DOM/) for Perl.com. For you, take your decoded content and give it to Mojo::DOM and do the same processing I've already done:

```
my $html = HTTP::Request->new( ... )->request( ... )->decoded_content;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $html );
my @results = $dom->find( ... )->...;
```